# Integrate $\int{\frac{x}{1+x^4}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Integrate $\displaystyle \int{\dfrac{x}{1+x^4}}dx$.

The best way I can think of doing this is by breaking $\dfrac{x}{1+x^4}$ into partial fractions but that would be messy.

Comment: Hint: Let $x^2=u$.

Comment: What was wrong with the previous solution?

Comment: What previous solution are you referring to?

Comment: It was correct and said $\dfrac{1}{2}\tan^{-1}(x^2)+C$.

Comment: I deleted my answer to let you solve it yourself (using the hint). Apparently someone else has posted a full solution, so I'll undelete it.

Comment: @Puzzled417: There was nothing *wrong* with your proposed strategy. We get the factorization $x^4+1=(x^2-x\sqrt{2}+1)(x^2+x\sqrt{2}+1)$. Now use partial fractions. Afterwards we will need to complete squares. As you point out, messy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\int \frac{x}{1+x^4}\, dx=\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{1}{1+\left(x^2\right)^2}\, d\left(x^2\right)=\frac{1}{2}\arctan x^2+C$$

Comment: +1 but i would let the OP do at least some of the work

Comment: Someone else has posted a full solution, so I'll leave this here then.

Answer (score 2):

$$\int{\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx}=\mathrm{arctan}(x)$$
The above is a standard integral. Using that, with $y=x^2$, thus $dy=2xdx$, we find:
$$\int{\frac{xdx}{1+x^4}}=\frac{1}{2}\int{\frac{2xdx}{1+\left(x^2\right)^2}}=\frac{1}{2}\int{\frac{dy}{1+y^2}}=\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{arctan}(y)=\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{arctan}(x^2)$$

Comment: You're missing $+C$.

Comment: Correct. I tend not to write $+C$ because I almost never find it useful.